# USB debugging is not list out my device

Tags: android, linux, adb, linux-device-driver, ubuntu-11.10

my htc device USB debugging is detecting in ubuntu 10.10  linux.

But its not detecting in Ubuntu 11.10 linux.

I am using the same 51 rules file. other device is detecting in both (i.e nexus..)

```
padmakumar@padmakumar-desktop:~$ lsusb
```

even `lsusb` is also not showing the information for the device in 11.10.

why? whats the reason?

Comment: Stupid question: Is USB debugging on on the device and does the device tell that it is connected to USB?

Comment: @Kimvais thanks for you comments. can you Edit it plz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick thought, May be the usb device id is wrong in rules file..

You can verify the device is getting detected or not by running "watch lsusb" and disconnecting and reconnecting the device while watch is running. If the device is getting detected you can know usb dev id

e.g.

#lsusb
Bus 001 Device 013: ID 0bb4:4e2a High Tech Computer Corp.

- 0bb4 is vendorid

hope this helps.

In case the device is getting detected and there is permissions issue - 
1. as root, adb kill-server
2. as root, adb start-server
3. adb devices
4. Now onwards non-su will also be able to use adb commands